# iOS:how to replace '\' with '/' in NSString?

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have a string:`http://192.168.1.127:8080/static\res\upload\headImage\2016-5-28/ffb8cbe68970440293635545a4d25d6f.png`

There are so many `'\'`(backslash) here.
I want to replace `'\'` to be `'/'`, how to do that?

Comment: To solve this question, you should better to ask your `javaer` or `phper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method :

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *replaced = [url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"/"];
```

**Swift**

```
let replaced = url.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "/")
```